# Mocking the Clock sysvar in solana_program_test

Tags: testing, program-test, sysvar, bankclient, clock

I have a program as follows:

- Some state is initialized with a `start_time`
- Another instruction can be executed on that state, but only if the clock sysvar has passed the given `start_time`

In my tests (using `solana_program_test` and the `banks_client`) I've tried the following:

This solution loops forever:

```
    loop {
        let clock: Clock = banks_client.get_sysvar().await.unwrap();
        if clock.unix_timestamp > data.start_time {
            break;
        }
        std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1));
    }
```

If I manually sleep for the required time, I get an error in the program that makes it seem as though the clock sysvar hasn't moved forward i.e:

```
    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs((data.start_time - clock.unix_timestamp) as u64));
```

Produces this:

```
[2022-07-18T14:17:20.530662358Z DEBUG solana_runtime::message_processor::stable_log] Program log: 5 seconds until vend starts...
[2022-07-18T14:17:20.531179736Z DEBUG solana_runtime::message_processor::stable_log] Program log: Vend hasn't started yet
```

This is where start time was initially set to `clock.unix_timestamp + 5`.

My question is:

- Does the banks client move the clock forward? If so, when/how?
- Is it possible to write to the clock sysvar and change the time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you're blocking the async executor with `std::thread::sleep()`. Try `tokio::time:sleep()` instead

Comment: Thanks, but same result as the original post with `tokio::time::sleep()` - still looks like the clock isn't moving.