# How to increase the system clock timestamp in tests?

Tags: anchor, anchor-test, clock

This is potentially related to [Mocking the Clock sysvar in solana_program_test](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/355/mocking-the-clock-sysvar-in-solana-program-test), but I didn't find a sufficient answer/discussion there.

I have a program instruction that contains logic such that instruction_b cannot be executed while the clock's current timestamp is less than the timestamp at instruction_a + some time.

How can I mock or fast-forward the clock's current timestamp such that I can test instruction_b?

e.g. I would like to write the following unit test:

```
1. execute instruction_a
2. fast-forward (1 day)
3. execute instruction_b
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Control time anchor test](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/5683/control-time-anchor-test)

Comment: @kise Not what I'm looking for. My example requires that the time be fast forwarded 1 day. It's not feasible to have a test run on a loop sleeping for a second until a day has passed.

Comment: Looks like it's not possible for tests written in JS/TS, but you can do something in Rust:https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/3748/7356

Comment: Thank you @Kise. It's unfortunate that the tooling is so immature, but good to know it can be done using Rust tests.